# Django DRF - using basic search filter to do an multiple OR search

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Im trying to do a multiple OR search with the basic Django filter. Ive tried the below URLs already but they only return the first result

api/circuit/?search=AB5814765;AB827451;AB0923784

using a comma returns no results also.

is there any syntax that will show multiple records built in or does something custom need making, ive tried a few custom attempts but they are all failing too

using an action like the below gives me a 404 when I try to do

api/circuit/ref_search/AB5814765|AB827451|AB0923784

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='ref_search/(?P<refs>[^/.]+)/', permission_classes=[IsAdminUser])
def ref_search(self, request, refs, *args, **kwargs):
    refs = refs.split('|')
    query = Q()
    for x in refs:
        q = Q(circuit__ref_no=x)
        query |= q
    queryset = DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(query)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

I also tried

api/circuit/ref=AB5814765|AB827451|AB0923784

```
def get_queryset(self):
    refs = self.request.query_params.get('ref', None)
    if refs is not None:
        refs = refs.split('|')
        query = Q()
        for x in refs:
            q = Q(status=x)
            query |= q
        queryset = queryset.filter(query)
    return queryset
```

my view:

```
class SiteCircuitDataROView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircuitSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    filter_class = Circuit
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
```

Comment: share your filter `Circuit`

Comment: Don't do this: `query = Q()` use `query =  Circuit.objects.none()`, otherwise it does not filter by status.

Comment: Circuit isn't a filter its a model

Comment: in which attempt the action or the get_queryset?

Comment: @AlexW either one you are using right now (both :)).

Comment: api/circuit/ref_search/AB5814765|AB827451|AB0923784 still gives me 404 and api/circuit/?ref=AB5814765|AB827451|AB0923784 gives me blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, using `__in` and call `api/circuit/?refs=AB5814765|AB827451|AB0923784`

```py
class SiteCircuitDataROView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircuitSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    filter_class = Circuit
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='ref_search/', permission_classes=[IsAdminUser])
    def ref_search(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        refs = self.request.get('refs', '').split('|')
        queryset = DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(ref__in=refs)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your view like below

```
class SiteCircuitDataROView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CircuitSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
        search = self.request.GET.get('search', '').split(',')
        if search:
           query = Q()
           for term in search:
               query = query | Q(circuit__ref_no__icontains=term)
           queryset = queryset.filter(query)
        return queryset
```

Now, send request like below url

```
api/circuit/?search=AB5814765,AB827451,AB0923784
```

Comment: @AlexW plz check my answer

Comment: local variable 'q' referenced before assignment